# Property 'onNext' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<Filer>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm creating an angular2 app and I've got a service that I want to be able to write to in one component and then read/update it in other components (routes).

Here's what my service looks like currently:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Filer } from './filer.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class FilerService {
  public _filer: Subject<Filer>;

  constructor() {
    this._filer = new Subject();
  }

  setSelected(ret: Filer) {
    let temp = ret;
    this._filer.next(temp);
  }

  get selected(): Observable<Filer> {
    return this._filer.asObservable();
  }

}
```

since I'm using `Subject`, only components that are subscribed will be able to see any values.  I tried changing it to a `BehaviorSubject`, based on the rxjs docs.  Here's what that looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Filer } from './filer.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class FilerService {
  public _filer: BehaviorSubject<Filer>;

  constructor() {
    this._filer = new BehaviorSubject({});
  }

  setSelected(ret: Filer) {
    let temp = ret;
    this._filer.onNext(temp);
  }

  get selected(): Observable<Filer> {
    return this._filer.asObservable();
  }

}
```

However, I get `Property 'onNext' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<Filer>'.`, so I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any ideas?

I'm on rxjs 5.0.0-beta.6.

Comment: it is probably called `next` instead of `onNext` if you use rxjs 5

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the latest angular2 then it uses rxjs 5, in which case you have to use `next()` and not `onNext()`.

Have a look at the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).